# NSight (NVIDIA) does not work correctly using 'Pause and Capture frame' functionality with Visual Studio

Tags: opengl, gpu, nvidia, nsight

I installed NSight for Visual Studio 2012 several days ago. But today there is something wrong with the 'Pause and Capture frame' functionality. Actually, when I click on the icon as showing below I don't have the frame scrubber in visual studio (the page showing the analysis page)!

Here's the steps I follow:

1) Click on 'NSIGHT' menu and 'Start Graphics Debugging'

[image]

2) The program is being launched in a window showing the NSIGHT GUI on it. I press the command 'CTRL + Z' and I click on the icon 'Pause and Capture frame' as follow:

[image]

Then have the following display:

[image]

But on my Visual Studio interface I don't have the 'Frame Scrubber' (the analysis page showing all the information about all the graphics pipeline).

I don't have this page:

[image]

I think I have unintentionally modified a propertie which disabled the loading of this page.

Does anyone can help me, please ?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to click on 'Window' menu and 'Reset Window Layout' as follow:

[image]

I hope this post will be helpfull for somebody!

Comment: This will reset all window layouts (design, debug, etc) which will work. A new instance of the API Inspector can be opened from the menu system using Nsight > Windows > API Inspector.

Answer (score 1):

The Nsight Visual Studio Graphics Debugger adds a number of new Toolwindows to Visual Studio. These toolwindows can be accesssed through the **Nsight > Windows** submenu.

After executing "Pause and Capture a Frame" the graphics debugger is in a paused replay mode. The graphics API state is available in the "API Instpector" toolwindow which can be opened using the command **Nsight > Windows > API Inspector**.

The API Inspector is a multi-instance toolwindow as are most of the graphics debugger toolwindows. This means that you can open the window multiple times. If you close all instances of the window it will not be re-opened when you "Pause and Capture a Frame". The toolwindow is persisted in the Visual Studio **Debug** Window Layout and will only be visible in Paused Mode.

For more information see the Nsight Visual Studio Edition User Guide section on the [API Inspector](http://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/index.html#developertools/desktop/api_inspector.htm)